# Problems with a UITableView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, memory, queue

I've got an app which stores images taken by the camera in a table view. I have a problem where the images (using apple's queuing system for memory management) are not able to load as fast as the user can scroll (it stops then jumps when the image loads) and sometimes the app crashes. This is on an iPod 5. I understand that this is because of the fact it cannot load the images quickly enough. Does anybody have any suggestions for how to do this? I know it can be done because of the existence of the music app and such.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this great tutorial.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/76341/use-nsoperation-nsoperationqueue-swift

It uses NSOperation to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Load images in background thread. You can use Dispatch_async or NSOperationQueue to get images in background. Your main thread will continue executing UI events.